# Where does IntelliJ IDEA store shelf changes on the local drive?

Tags: intellij-idea, file-location

I want to write a small backup script that would take my shelf changes in IntelliJ from my local drive and put them on a network drive. But I can't locate the path to where these are stored on my local drive.

Any ideas?

Comment: Slightly different issue, but if Google took you here because you can't find your Shelf tab, check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71167546/1679571

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For me it's `$user.home/.IntelliJIdea90/config/shelf`

I'm not sure if that changes on OSX or not.  It seems like it might be different, but once you find the .IntelliJIdea90 directory, it's in `/config/shelf`.

**Update for comment**
Here is my .IntelliJIdea80/config/shelf directory after shelving some changes in 8.1.3:

```
skrall@skralldesktop:~/.IntelliJIdea80/config/shelf$ ls
AnotherTestOfshelving.patch
skrall@skralldesktop:~/.IntelliJIdea80/config/shelf$
```

I'll startup my Windows VM and see if it's the same place on Windows.

**Update With Windows**

Same place.  This is Vista, so it's C:\Users\skrall\.IntelliJ90\config\shelf  Can you search your local hard drive for a directory named shelf?  Or, if that doesn't work, search for *.patch

Comment: NOPE - I use WIndows XP and IntelliJIdea80 folder in my user's folder doesn't have a config/shelf subfolder. I do have there code changes shelf so it must be stored somewhere, right?

Comment: I loaded up my version of 8.1.3.  It's in config/shelf for me.

Comment: I don't have that path at all. Is there any way to check in IntelliJ what that path is defined as?

Comment: Downloading IntelliJ for Windows.  I'll let you know once it's done.

Comment: Updated information for Windows.  Basically the same, not sure what could be going on...

Comment: I'm using CVS for my version control... I wonder if that makes a difference... I wouldn't think so, but I guess it's possible

Comment: On Mac OS X, these are in ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea90/shelf

Comment: In Intellij 14, they are stored within your project under $PROJECT_HOME/.idea/shelf

Comment: I seems to have changed - I see some old shelves in my old idea folders: `$HOME/.IntelliJIdea15/config/shelf/` (already v. 15 but probably from EAP times), but all new ones are in `$PROJECT_HOME/.idea/shelf`.

Answer (score 31):

Instead of giving the fish, here is how to fish:

1. [Find an action](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/navigating-to-action.html) item: 
   <kbd>⌘</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (on a Mac) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (on Windows/Linux)
2. Type "*change shelve*"[image]
3. Check the location where it is being stored[image]

Answer (score 21):

IntelliJ IDEA 15 on linux, shelved changes seem to be stored as individual files in the project directory, under the `.shelf` directory.

Comment: Also applies to Intellij 16 on Windows

Answer (score 19):

Idea can also store shelved changes in `<projectFolder>/.idea/shelf/` directory. Try to check this option.

Comment: This is perfect answer for windows machines!

Comment: True for Macos too!

Answer (score 7):

For IntelliJ 10 on mac, for me its in ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea10/Shelf

Comment: Now changed to `~/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC11/shelf`

Answer (score 3):

IntelliJ IDEA 12 on Mac, stores them in ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea12/shelf/*.patch

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA 12 on Windows7, default location

```
%UserHome%\.IdeaIC12\config\shelf\*.patch
```

i.e. **_IDE_config_folder_**\shelf\*.patch

Note non default IDE config folder location can be looked up in _IDEA_HOME_\bin\idea.properties
 idea.config.path=${user.home}/.IdeaIC/config