# How to recover the deleted shelved changes in git?

Tags: git, android-studio

I have made some changes to master branch without commit just shelved those changes and then accidently deleted those shelved changes. Is there any possibility of recovering those shelved changes ?

Comment: Do you mean "stashed" as in `git stash save`? And you did a `git stash clear`?

Comment: I found this in the docs; perhaps it helps: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#git-stash-Recoveringstashesthatwerecleareddroppederroneously

Comment: I have integrated git in androidstudio, shelved those changes and deleted. didnt use any stash commands

Comment: @Schwern Android Studio has a "shelf" menu item that is distinct from "stash" with git integration. I have never used it as I prefer to make sure everything is in Git and not something else.

Comment: Unfortunately, [this question + answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497445/android-studio-shelved-changes-disappeared-not-even-in-the-idea-shelf-director) seem to indicate that changes were not stored in `git`. Try looking for `android-studio` specific hacks, or run some disk recovery tool on your system.

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is 11 month old but I think this should be mentioned, even if it's a bit off topic.
In Android Studio, there is a "Shelf" tab in Version Control tool window where you can right click and "Unshelve" your files.

Comment: This may be better suited as a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Since shelving appears to add the item to the object database, so that it can be unshelved later, yes it is recoverable.

When you run `git add`, or stash or shelve an item, git actually places the object in the object database.  It's now unreferenced and will *eventually* be garbage collected.  But until then you can use a tool called [`git-recover`](https://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/introducing_git_recover.html) to find that in your object database and recover it.

Comment: Android Studio has a "Shelf" menu item/command in its VCS integration. I do not have any idea how it is implemented and do not use it since I just use the git integration and its stash command. I just know that this exists and is probably what the OP is referring to.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: didn't work, recovered some files in the branch other than the expected file

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  I'll have to figure out where "shelving" _does_ put its files.