# Pycharm - Shelved Changes... now I'd like it back

Tags: version-control, pycharm, unshelve

I was working on branch1 but had to switch to branch2, so while in branch1 (also, I didn't commit) I went to VCS-> Shelve Changes... then hoped onto branch2 and did stuff.
Now I'm back at branch1 and can't find how to get my shelved changes back.
[VCS dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0HNA.jpg)

I've read this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/shelving-and-unshelving-changes.html#555de
but I don't have a Shelf tab.
So I read this on how to get a Shelf tab: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/shelf-tab.html
but I don't have View | Tool Windows | ***Version Control | Shelf***
[View dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkUv2.jpg)

[What shows up when I try views - tool window - git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUcAP.png)

Comment: Slightly different issue, but if Google took you here because you can't find your Shelf tab, check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71167546/1679571

Answer (score 0):

Menu has been updated, try with `View - Tool Windows - Git - Shelf`

Comment: Hi @user2235698 :)  This is just showing me Git and my local/remote branches and commits but I don't see Shelf here.

Comment: Do you have the `Git - Uncommitted Changes - Show Shelf` menu option?

Comment: No I don't see that. I've added a screenshot in my question of what shows up when I try view - tool windows - git