# How do you refresh the shelf in an IntelliJ project?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, editor

I have a project I'm working on in IntelliJ with several items in its shelf. Occasionally I've noticed something goes wrong with the shelf and none of the items display correctly, instead I just see gray arrows on the side like usual, but no content when clicking on them.

I know that the shelf patches are still there, and not corrupted, because I can manually import/apply patches to my code base. I can also still create patches, although they will not show up correctly in the shelf menu either.

At the moment the only way of fixing this I've found is to simply recheck out my entire code base as another project, and then import the patches manually to the new projects shelf. This is obviously very cumbersome, but not being able to use the shelf feature is also very detrimental to the way I work.

Is there some method to force an intelliJ project to reconsider all of its shelf items, to try and fix this issue without going through the massive work around of rechecking out my project files?

---

EDIT: These patches are locally stored copies of source code changes, not on a separate branch via SVN.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's relevant, but you should probably include what version of IntelliJ IDEA and if it's Community or Ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen the behavior you describe, but I can give a very generic answer to "IDEA is acting funny", as you haven't said you've tried it yet:

In the File menu, choose "Invalidate Caches / Restart". This will have IntelliJ IDEA clear its cache, which every once in a while doesn't match reality.

Another approach might be to move the shelf files somewhere else, do Invalidate Caches, and then move them back (and maybe Invalidate Caches again). (It sounds like you're already familiar with moving the shelf files, but see [Where does IntelliJ IDEA store shelf changes on the local drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2683179/65839) for details on where they live.) I haven't tried this, though.

You could also confirm that they're listed properly in the `.idea/workspace.xml` file, under `<component name="ShelveChangesManager" …>`. Depending on the issue, perhaps some manual fixes in there may be needed?